# flexbox div goes off screen on small screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Code first:

```css
html {
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

body {
 display:flex;
  flex:1;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  overflow-y:auto;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.block1 {
  justify-content:center;
  background-color:green;
  display:flex;
  width:300px;
  min-height:150px;
}

.block2 {
  background-color:blue;
  display:flex;
  min-height:300px;
    width:500px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="block1">
  <img src="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M252f960f4a4f32c22914d8d87623f066o0&pid=15.1">
</div>
<div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

I have two blocks in a container. I want them centered on the screen.
The issue is when the screen height is small,  I have a scrollbar that appear but the first block have a part that go offscreen (is invisible)

To reproduce, decrease the height of the jsfiddle preview window. You will understand what I mean by going off screen.

The expected behavior is to let the scroll bar appear and keep the div visible.

I tried by setting flex-shrink to 0 on every element but it isn't working...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can make use of Flexbox's `auto` margins.

1. Remove `justify-content: center` from `.container`.
2. Add `margin-top: auto` to `.block1`.
3. Add `margin-bottom: auto` to `.block2`.

```css
html {
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

body {
 display:flex;
  flex:1;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  overflow-y:auto;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}

.block1 {
  justify-content:center;
  background-color:green;
  display:flex;
  width:300px;
  min-height:150px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.block2 {
  background-color:blue;
  display:flex;
  min-height:300px;
  width:500px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="block1">
  <img src="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M252f960f4a4f32c22914d8d87623f066o0&pid=15.1">
</div>
<div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So easy that I didn't think at it, so I manage differently my html without using justify-content. Frustrating that I still don't understand why my full flexbox design isn't working but at least I can move on. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Glad to help! Flexbox is quite a learning curve, but you'll get there eventually!

Answer (score -1):

You can add `position: absolute; top: 0` to the container:

```css
html {
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

body {
 display:flex;
  flex:1;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  overflow-y:auto;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.block1 {
  justify-content:center;
  background-color:green;
  display:flex;
  width:300px;
  min-height:150px;
}

.block2 {
  background-color:blue;
  display:flex;
  min-height:300px;
    width:500px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="block1">
  <img src="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M252f960f4a4f32c22914d8d87623f066o0&pid=15.1">
</div>
<div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I set width:100%, ok on this sample but unfortunately it doesn't work on my project (more complex than this sample). Maybe I will try to change the sample to reproduce the bug even with position:absolute and top:0